# How to stretch table to full page size

Tags: tables

I am typesetting folderlabels using the ticket-pakage.
This works quite nice but since I have different widths I try to add more flexibility by using relatve instead of absolute positions. My current solution uses a table where all the stuff goes in. I want the 'topic' (rotated) at the bottom of the label (page in the mwe).

How do I achieve this?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{letter}
\usepackage[emptycrossmark]{ticket}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=2mm}
\unitlength=1mm
\hoffset=-16.2mm
\ticketNumbers{1}{4}
\ticketSize{192}{61}
\ticketDistance{0}{0}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{}%neccessary to 'clean' the 

\newcommand{\filelabel}[3]{
  \ticket{
    \put(0,0){
      \begin{sideways}
        \begin{minipage}[t][\ticketHeight][t]{\ticketWidth}
          \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\ticketHeight}@{}}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{
              \includegraphics[width=.8\ticketHeight]{unilogo_cut}
              }\\[2mm]
            \hspace*{\fill}\huge#2\hspace*{2mm}\\[2mm]
              #3\\
            \multicolumn{1}{r|}{
              \begin{rotate}{90}
                \Huge#1%this entry should go to the bottom of the label
              \end{rotate}
            }
          \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
      \end{sideways}
    }
  }
}




\newcommand{\entry}[2]{
  \textbf{\Large#1}
  #2
  \vspace{5mm}
}

% and here are the labels...
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\filelabel{Versicherungen}{1}{
  \entry{PKV}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Vertragswerk
    \end{itemize}
  }
  \entry{Haftpflicht}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Vertragswerk
    \end{itemize}
  }
  \entry{Hausrat}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sonstiges
    \end{itemize}
  }
}


\ticketNumbers{1}{7}
\ticketSize{192}{35}
\filelabel{DSS / ICT}{1}{
  \entry{ADSP}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Script
      \item Übungen
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Mitschrift
        \item Selbstrechen
        \end{itemize}
      \item Fragezettel
      \item Altklausuren
    \end{itemize}
  }
  \entry{Wireless Comm.}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Script
      \item Übungen
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Mitschrift
        \item Selbstrechen
        \end{itemize}
      \item Fragezettel
      \item Altklausuren
    \end{itemize}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear you describe a rotated topic but your example has no rotation? `\begin{tabular}{|@{}p{\textwidth}@{}|}` also looks a bit odd, it will make an over-full line as there is a parbox of width `\textwidth` but also two vertical rules and a paragraph indent. the `this will expand` `p` column box will expand if you add more text, but how can a one-line text expand?

Comment: I agree that it looks odd. I tried to keep it as small as possible but it seems it lacks the intention. Assume we have a "topic" called 'invoice'. The original code used absolute positions with \put{x,y}. Since the width of the labels change, the topic is positioned too far off or right in the middle of the label. I thought I can  solve this with tables but am open for new ideas.

Comment: sorry I can only suggest that you edit the question. I can not guess the intended meaning enough to suggest any code.

Comment: Is `myticket` somewhere available?

Comment: It was the actual ticket.sty from ctan which I renamed since the one in my texlive distribution was too old and lacks a function. I have edited the above example.